# xsd pattern for comma-separated list of single characters

Tags: list, xsd, schema

I have a problem in the xsd schema below: how can I restrict comma-separated string to only one character like this

```
    <status>A,B,C,D</status>
```

Currently I am using the code below to create a comma-separated list of strings.

```
<xs:simpleType name="order">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      Comma-separated list of anything
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[^,]+(,\s*[^,]+)*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    <xs:element name="status">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

to validate:

```
  <status>A</status>
  <status>A,</status>
  <status>A,B</status>
  <status>A,B,C,D</status>
  <status>A,B,C,D,</status>
```

and avoid

```
  <status>AA</status>
  <status>AA,</status>
  <status></status>
  <status>AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,</status>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution its working good but for one case it should work like comma at the end should not be mandatory please update '<status>A,B</status>

Comment: Thanks bro for your quick response i have updated your response a little bit for the case if the list have only one item without comma then it should be like this (([A-Z][,]?)+)([A-Z]?)) please update and verify my change.

Comment: Yes, it is correct to validate <status>A</status>, <status>A,</status>, <status>A,B</status>, and <status>A,B,</status> as well

Comment: :( now this pattern (([A-Z][,]?)+)([A-Z]?))  also accepting multiple characters like <status>AAA,BBB,CCC</status> please check this case i have tried many patterns. please update this is the only case left to handle

Comment: Please share your all required types to handle to ease.

Comment: <status>A</status>, <status>A,</status>, <status>A,B</status>, and <status>A,B,C,D,E,F</status> AND it should not accept multiple characters like <status>AAAA,BBB,CCCC</status> <status>AA,B,CCC</status>

Comment: please remove last parantheses from the regular expression it is creating problem on server. InvalidRegex: Pattern value '((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))' is not a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Navin Rawat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585230/5445670), just different (and simpler) regex:

```
<xs:element name="status">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z](,[A-Z])*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632147/navin-rawat)[Navin Rawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632147/navin-rawat)'s answer **allows the use of commas**, it is *probably* **not** the best/most `XML` solution to your problem.

A **"***better***"** solution, would be to use an [XML list](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_list.asp), as in the following schema code:

```
<xs:schema>
<xs:simpleType name="character">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="1" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="order">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
    Space-separated list of single characters
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:list itemType="character" />
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, is uses a `xs:restriction`, rather than a regular expression, to enforce the length of each string being 1.  The only drawback is that it requires the strings to be *whitespace delineated*, rather than comma-separated.